# swift5 Use of undeclared type 'CLLocaitonDegress'

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, swift5, cllocation

I am tried to get value of latitude, longitude from my app .
but there is some error with "Use of undeclared type 'CLLocaitonDegress'" this message..
I don't understand what happend to my code ??

```
func fetchWeather(latitude: CLLocaitonDegress, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) {
        let urlString = "\(weatherURL)&lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)"
        performRequest(urlString: urlString)
    }

//MARK: -CLLocationManagerDelegate

extension WeatherViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.last {
            let lat: Double = location.coordinate.latitude
            let lon: Double = location.coordinate.longitude
            weatherManager.fetchWeather(cityName: String, latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Did you `import CoreLocation`?

Comment: `CLLocaitonDegress`. There is a typo (a "it" instead of "ti) there. Delete it, rewrite it letting completion help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace in your code:
func fetchWeather(latitude: CLLocaitonDegress, longitude: CLLocationDegrees)

with this:

func fetchWeather(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add import CoreLocation under import UIKit

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
```